# returning value in MySql into php table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a strange issue.

Once connected to the database, I can return only one column of values (the FG-PCT column).

Here is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT sstorm_players.player_LastName  AS 'Full Name',          
sum(sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_GP) AS 'GP',
sstorm_players.player_PlayerID AS 'PlayerID',
sstorm_players.player_Current AS 'Current',
sstorm_players.player_YEAR2011_12 AS '2011-12',
Sum(sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_FGM) AS 'FGM', 
Sum(sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_FGA) AS 'FGA',
ROUND((sum(sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_FGM) / sum(sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_FGA)*100),1 AS    'FG-PCT' 

FROM sstorm_players INNER JOIN sstorm_rawstats1 
ON sstorm_players.player_PlayerID = sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_PlayerID 
 WHERE sstorm_players.player_PlayerID = sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_PlayerID
GROUP BY sstorm_players.player_PlayerID
HAVING sstorm_players.player_YEAR2011_12 = true 
order by ROUND((sum(sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_FGM) / sum(sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_FGA)*100),1) desc";
```

When I echo the selected values, I can only return one of the columns (the FC-PCT column).

Here is an example of my echo statements:

```
// this statement has values that do not get returned
echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$row_color'><strong>" . $row['FGM)'] . "</strong></td>";

// this statement has values that do not get returned
echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$row_color'><strong>" . $row['FGA)'] . "</strong></td>";

// this statement has values that get returned
echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='$row_color'><strong>" . $row['FG-PCT'] . "</strong></td>";
```

I am not echoing all of the columns in my query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a right paren in your array key which is why it can't access the values:

`$row['FGM)']` should be `$row['FGM']` and

`$row['FGA)']` should be `$row['FGA']`

Comment: I feel so silly.

Helps to have a set of clear eyes.

Comment: No problem, if everything is working now, please mark this post as the answer, thanks!